# Laravel excel: read specific rows while using collections

Tags: excel, laravel, collections, chunked

Laravel version: 7.x

I have a test data file of `1161 rows`, which needs to be uploaded via ajax and rendered in the editable format, in case of validations failed. So I am using `Excel::toCollection(...)`. But, even with this small amount of data, the application hangs for a while, until the rendering is complete.

To handle this situation I reading only 50 rows at a time, validate and append in the form via ajax. However, it has reduced the load and also decrease the rendering time, but each time I have to read the entire file and get the next chuck out of it.

Here is my code:

```php
$arrayPost = request()->only([
    'start',
    'limit',
]);

$arrayExcel = \Excel::toCollection(new SubscriberImport(), <uploaded_file_path>);
$arrayExcel = array_slice($arrayExcel, $arrayPost['start'], $arrayPost['limit']);

$validated = $this->validateExcel($arrayExcel);

if($validated->fails())
{
    # return with error
    return view('<form_path>', [
        'arrayExcel' => $arrayExcel,
    ])->withErrors($validated->getMessageBag()->toArray());
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to fetch the specific rows from the file.?

Comment: Have you tried chunk reading? https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/chunk-reading.html

Comment: I have tried this. But, this didn't solve my problem. Because, I need to read only 50 rows at a time and the next set of 50 rows will be handled in the next ajax request and so on, until the all rows have been appended to the form.